# Broadcast receiver: check the wifi presence

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have done a code exploiting the Broadcast receiver in order to call the method on Receive when the status of connection change and show a toast indicating the change. In that sense I have a separated class in which is implemented the broadcast receiver in  that way:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";

  @Override

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      // Shows a toast when the connectivity state change
      Toast.makeText(context, "stato wifi cambiato",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d("prova", "action: "
                 + intent.getAction())     

  }
}
```

it works recalling correctly the method OnReceive() when there is a network state change and showing the toast.

In the main file I have put a code that once a button is pressed it verifies if the Wifi is connected or not also in this case showing a toast with a message "Wifi connected: true/false" depending on the presence or not of connectivity. The code that works also in this case is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo =     connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
    final boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
    String wifiStateText = "No State";
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
    Button prova = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    prova.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            CharSequence text = "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        }
    });

}
```

Now I'm trying to embedding the last part of the code in the method OnReceive() defined above in order to let's do all in automatic once there is a network connectivity change ando so I the resulting code of the Broadcast receiver is that one:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
  // Verifica se il wifi è connesso

  @Override

  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

      // Shows a toast when the connectivity state change
      Toast.makeText(context, "stato wifi cambiato",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      Log.d("prova", "action: "
                 + intent.getAction());


      ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
            final boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
          String wifiStateText = "No State";
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);

      // Toast that shows if the wifi is connected
      CharSequence text = "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();     


  }


}
```

In that case I get this error:

```
the method getsystemservice(string) is undefined for the type Receiver
```

on this line:

```
getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

What's wrong? What have I to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `'context'` parameter: `context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);`

The `BroadcastReceiver` is not derived from `Context`.